# Can't access to array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I create an array and I put other array in each index.

But the problem is, when I make:

> console.log(coords[0]);

This through me: undefined

If i make:

> console.log(coords);

Show me this:

[image]

Code:

```
var coords = [];

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&osm_type=R&osm_id=2532299&polygon_geojson=1',
        data: { get_param: 'value' },
        success: function (data) {

            $.each(data.geojson.coordinates[0], function( index, value ) {

                if(typeof value[0] !== 'undefined' && typeof value[1] !== 'undefined') {
                    coords.push([value[0], value[1]]);
                }
            });
        }
    });

    console.log(coords);
    console.log(coords[0]);
```

Comment: JavaScript is an *asynchronous* language. Your code assumes it's synchronous. `coords[0]` is only defined after the clients received the response.

Comment: because the console lies - hover over the blue `i` in the console to see why you can see the whole, asynchronously filled, array

Comment: `coords` is an empty array until AFTER the `$.ajax` call is finished. And that happens after the `$.each` of your `success` function. Move your `console.log` calls to after the `$.each`

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 - no, javascript is **not** an asynchronous language. The asynchronous functions are asynchronous, but that doesn't make the language "asynchronous"

Comment: @JaromandaX JavaScript **is** an asynchronous language. You would have to define an event loop if it's not.

Comment: add `while(true);` to your code ... is it asynchronous @Derek朕會功夫?

Comment: @JaromandaX That's not what an event loop is. But anyway, JS is inherently asynchronous and can go between functions in an arbitrary order. That's what makes it truly asynchronous. Notice that being asynchronous doesn't mean concurrent.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I know what an event loop is, that wasn't an attempt to show one!! You can stand by your misguided claim that JS is an asynchronous language if you want. You'd be wrong though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because your array is not yet filled with information when it reaches `console.log(coords[0]);`, You must remember the Async functionality .ajax()

If you want to make sure the the function has finished to start any othe process, you can use .done() at the end, like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body
}).done(function() {
  $( this ).addClass( "done" );
});
```

Check it out on [JQuery Ajax Doc](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)